# Extbase not visible in Admin Tools

Tags: typo3

I've installed Typo3 (6.2.15) and have to create an extension. However, the Extbase is not visible in my Admin Tools Menu. This extension is installed by default (6.2.15 does not give the option to A/D this extension). Anyone got a hint?

Comment: Are you maybe searching for the extension `extension_builder`? You'd have to install that one using the extension manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extbase is just the Framework. It doesn't come along with any Backend Module to kickstart the extension.

To create an extension, follow the official documentation https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/ or use the extension named by Jost `extension_builder`.
It can be that this extension is not compatible / working with 6.2. In that case install it in an older TYPO3 Installation as it just kickstarts the extension.